# Checking if Boolean Mathematical Formula is in the Proper Form

Tags: python, recursion, boolean, logic, phrase

I am creating a program that takes in a boolean expression as a string and converts the infix formula to postfix, while making sure the formula is in a valid form. What I'm having a hard time doing is figuring out a way to check if the inputed formula is valid or not. **NO IMPORTING** is permitted (use built-in python functions/methods), loops and recursion are allowed. If the formula is invalid, return None.

The formula can contain:

```
variables in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
operators in '-+*'
```

where - is NOT, + is OR, * is AND

Here are some valid formulas (as Python strings).

```
"x" 
"-y" 
"(x*y)" 
"((-x+y)*(-y+x))"
```

Here are some strings that are not formulas.

```
"X" variable not lower case letter 
"x*y" missing parentheses 
"-(x)" extraneous parentheses 
"(x+(y)*z)" mismatched parentheses
```

Some conversion examples are:

```
(x+y) -> xy+
(x*y) -> xy*
-(x+y) -> xy+-
-x -> x-
((x*y)+(z*x)) -> xy*zx*+
```

A full working program isn't necessary, an algorithm to check if the formula is valid or not is fine.

My current implementation to convert formula from infix to postfix:

```
def infix_to_postfix(infix_expression):
    precedence  = {}
    precedence["*"] = 2
    precedence["+"] = 2
    precedence["-"] = 2
    precedence["("] = 1
    storage_stack = Stack()
    postfix_list = []
    tokenList = list(infix_expression)
    for token in tokenList:
        if(token not in "-+*()"):
            postfix_list.append(token)
        elif(token == '-'):
            storage_stack.push(token)
        elif(token == '('):
            storage_stack.push(token)
        elif(token == ')'):
            topToken = storage_stack.pop()
            while(topToken != '('):
                postfix_list.append(topToken)
                topToken = storage_stack.pop()
        else:
            while(not storage_stack.is_empty() and precedence[storage_stack.peek()] >= precedence[token]):
                postfix_list.append(storage_stack.pop())
            storage_stack.push(token)
    while(not storage_stack.is_empty()):
        postfix_list.append(storage_stack.pop())
    result = "".join(postfix_list)
    return result
```

I need to find a way to check that the formula is valid **while** changing the positions of the operators and variables.

Edit:

I've come up with part of an algorithm to check if the formula is valid or not:

```
((a+b)*(c+d))
F1 = (a+b)
F2 = (c+d)
((a+b)*(c+d)) = (F1 * F2)
If F1 and F2 are valid, then the whole thing is valid.
```

A formula enclosed with parenthesis is valid if:
There is ( and ), there is either a + or * in between 2 sub-formulas, and both sub-formulas are valid.

I have this idea of checking, but I have no idea how to implement it. Most likely recursion.

Comment: `(x+y)` is valid, `-x` is valid, but `(-x)` not? Isn't that strange?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Comment: As best I can figure out, you've posted a partial problem description and asked us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Elmex80s I understand that its strange, but that just how it has to be. The conditions for parentheses are for necessary things, like (x+-(y*z)), not excessive, like (((-(x)))).

Comment: @Prune I may be asking for some help on my homework, but I am not asking for a complete solution for homework (doing it all for me). All I'm asking for is a little help on coming up with an algorithm that can check if a formula is valid or not.

Comment: Do you have a formal definition of "valid formulas"? Your description is a bit vague.  In any event -- what have you tried? Perhaps you can start by writing a function which will identify the main connective of a valid formula (and whose failure will indicate an invalid formula). The notion of parenthesis depth might prove useful.

Comment: @JohnColeman 

Here are some valid formulas (as Python strings).
• "x"
• "-y"
• "(x*y)"
• "((-x+y)*-(-y+x))"

Here are some strings that are not formulas.
• "X" variable not lower case letter
• "x*y" missing parentheses
• "-(x)" extraneous parentheses
• "(x+(y)*z)" mismatched parentheses

Comment: A good specification shouldn't depend on a list of examples given in the hope that the reader might be able to guess your intentions. Coming up with a precise definition of well-formed formulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula ) is the first step towards writing a function to recognize them.

Comment: Also, please note that converting between any two of infix prefix, and postfix is a long-solved problem in expression evaluation.  You should have no question about that unless there's a specific problem with your implementation of a known algorithm.  You haven't posted any such problem.

Comment: Its not the converting from infix to postfix that I'm having a problem with. The problem I'm having is that it accepts all formulas that are balanced (same number of open and close bracket) and follow all rules except for the extraneous parentheses case. My question is just asking how would I detect a formula that has too many parenthesis, like (-x) or ((x+y)).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, however here is a potential solution to someone having the same issue.

```
import re


def formula(string):
    if not string: return 0
    string = re.sub("[^0-9+*/%-=]", "", string)

try:
    string, result = string.split("=")
    return eval(string) == int(result)
except:
    return 0
```